# Changing values in the chart in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, output

I have a simple shiny application and I don't know why the values on the chart change when I choose  multiple items from a list. Below my example and images with bad charts.

**ui**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("App test"),

    sidebarPanel(
        h3(" "),
        selectizeInput("name",
                       label = "Code",
                       choices = unique(data$Product),
                       multiple = T,
                       options = list(maxItems = 5, placeholder = 'Select a code'),
                       selected = "46")
        ),

    mainPanel(
        plotOutput("trendPlot")
    )
)
)
```

**server**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$trendPlot <- renderPlot({

            df_trend <- data[data$Product == input$name, ]

            ggplot(df_trend) +
                geom_line(aes(x = Month, y = Value, group = Product, colour = Product)) +
                theme(legend.position = "bottom")              

    })
})
```

Head my data:

```
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Product Month Value
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 46      Jan     188
2 46      Feb     277
3 46      Mar     317
4 46      Apr     367
5 46      May     329
6 46      Jun     318
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Multiple items from a list? You have used 'Product' column as list from the tibble. The column has only one unique value '46'. When I run your code, all I get is one option in the input which is 46 preselected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data set above only includes '46' for Product so cannot reproduce. However, I suspect the problem is how you are filtering data, allowing for multiple inputs with `selectizeInput`.

Right now you filter data:

```
df_trend <- data[data$Product == input$name, ]
```

Which is fine if `input$name` is a single value. However, with multiple inputs (e.g., 46 and 92), then `input$name` contains those two values, and you need a different kind of comparison.

To subset your data based on multi-value matching (like matching a vector), try instead:

```
df_trend <- data[data$Product %in% input$name, ]
```